# Why is there no CallerTypeNameAttribute in .NET 4.5?

Tags: .net, clr

With .NET 4.5, the CLR team added:

- [`CallerFilePathAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute)
- [`CallerLineNumberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerlinenumberattribute)
- [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute)

Why wasn't one added for the type of the caller?

Comment: Does the member name contain the type name as a prefix?

Comment: @CodesInChaos it doesnt look like it.

Comment: The standard response for "Why doesn't X have Y?" is "Why should have X have Y?" Real use cases for the three attributes you list were considered. I'm curious, what's your use case for the type of the caller?

Comment: @hvd For example to use it together with the member name to look up the memberinfo. Personally I would have liked a `CallerMemberInfoAttribute` instead of `CallerMemberNameAttribute`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos It wouldn't work for that. The caller member name is not unique and not designed to be. But yes, a `CallerMemberInfoAttribute` would be nice for that (if it existed).

Comment: There's just no way to make everybody happy implementing this.  What's the type for Base.Method?  What's the type for an extension method?

Comment: @HansPassant, it would appear the types would be Base and the static class the extension method was defined in. Seems obvious to me.

Comment: There is a proposal for additional caller attributes: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/87

Answer (score 2):

This is difficult for someone outside the design team to answer but I would say that there is not a strong use case for `CallerTypeNameAttribute`.

The file and line attributes give you extended information for logging routines that would be otherwise impossible to obtain. The member name allows logging and simplifies the implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` while also allowing safe name refactoring without the need to search strings.

The caller type can already be passed to a given method by using `typeof(CurrentType).Name` so it probably does not merit an extra attribute. You could say that the caller member name could also already be obtained using `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod` but that probably always forces reflection and the `typeof` is probably optimized away so you already get the benefit of safe refactoring and a lesser impact on performance.

The only downside of using `typeof` instead of the possible attribute would be that the attribute approach would not be affected by obfuscation.